# How to return data to an ajax succes callback

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I want to call an action via an ajax call with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: Craft.getActionUrl(_this.options.updateRestockAction),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log('error');
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log('complete');
    }
});
```

My action is being called successfully. However, I can't find out how to return data to the success callback. Any idea how to do this? I'm using Craft 3.

Thanks

Comment: Do you return an object of type `Response` in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robin mentions, your controller needs to return an object of type Response, and in your case you probably want to return it with the format set to json. There's a helper method in Craft's `Controller` class, `asJson`, which is handy for this. Example:

```
public function actionMyControllerAction()
{
    $result = ['my' => 'data'];
    return $this->asJson($result);
}
```

This should give you back an object for `data` with a key of `my` with value `data`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Along with correcting a small typo "success: function" instead of "succes: function"